# Asp to Aspx .net 4.0

Tags: asp-classic, asp.net-4.0

can anyone tell me how to convert ASP project to asp.net web application.

I tried this url but was not able to convert it.
http://www.asp101.com/articles/paolo/asp2aspnet/default.asp

I am trying to convert asp application to .net 4.0 web application.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool provided by Microsoft to do such thing.
Anywyay, you might not be fully .Net 4.0 compatible at the end, you certainly will have to correct some issues manually.
http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/migration-assistants/asp-to-aspnet

Comment: +1 - this will only upgrade to asp.net 1.1 - there is no way to go straight from classic asp to asp.net 4.0 - this is a good intermediate step

Comment: thats good enough for me, I can easily port from 1.1 to 4.0
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, in my experience, there is no easy way to migrate from 1 to the other, its a case of buying visual studio and creating a asp.net 4.0 solution in this context. then creating the functionality in the project

im sure this is NOT what you wanted to hear :(

Comment: :) i hoped i could hear, that it can be ported as i didnt wanted to rewrite my application in asp.net 4.0